# Severe (in my eyes at least) issue with positioning (turtle module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I made a simple game, where the user needs to get back to the same position in a specified number of moves. However, the code to do with the positioning that recognises whether the user has returned to the initial position does not seem to work.

This is the code that specifies the starting positioning of the turtle just in case:

```
my_turtle.setposition(0.00, 0.00)
```

Here is that code (only the part that deals with the positioning):

```
if my_turtle.position() == (0.00, 0.00) and tries == score:
    print("Well done")
        break
elif my_turtle.position() == (0.00, 0.00) and (tries > score or score > tries):
    print("Return to original position in exactly moves")
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work do you mean it just doesn't trigger when you think it should?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be because it is very difficult to get the turtle to go to point (0,0) exactly, so it might be better to set boundaries instead:

```
if 10>my_turtle.xcor()>-10 and 10>my_turtle.ycor()>-10 and tries == score:
    print("Well done")
    break
elif 10>my_turtle.xcor()>-10 and 10>my_turtle.ycor()>-10 and tries != score:
    print("Return to original position in exactly moves")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help; I just tried this and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Turtles wander a floating point plane.  As your turtle moves beyond home `(0, 0)` about the screen and eventually returns, it can accumlate some floating point noise, e.g. `(0.0001, -0.000)`.  So using an integer comparison like `==` won't work.  Instead we can use the `distance()` method:

```
if my_turtle.distance(0, 0) < 10:

    if tries == score:
        print("Well done")
        break

    print("Return to original position in exactly moves")
```

The `distance()` method is flexible in that along with separate coordinates, it can also accept a tuple coordinate, or even another turtle!

Comment: I never realized that we can pass a tuple into ``distance()``.

Comment: Oh right, I see. That makes sense; thank you very much!

Comment: The code works; thanks again. Can you explain why you would put  ' < 10  ' because I'm a little confused about that part?

Comment: @Amziino `my_turtle.distance(0, 0)` will return the distance between the center of `my_turtle` and the coordinate `(0,0)`. So it means if the distance is smaller than 10 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.